# Linq Query instead of Contains Operator for Performance issue

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have to Pull all customers whose ids are in the list

I have a list of CustomerID`s

**List custidlist=new List{1,2,3....etc.}();**

i have to write a linq query to get all customers whose id`s are in the above list

**custidlist**.

var customers=db.Customers.Where(c=> custidlist.**Contains**(c.customerid));

Using **Contains** is not good in performance issue.

Can we use COMPARE OPERATOR LIKE THIS

var customers=db.Customers.Where(c=> custidlist.**Compare**(c.customerid)); **????**

I Heard Compare is best for **Performance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is Linq to SQL / Entities your Linq `Contains` query will be translated to a SQL statement roughly like:

```
select * from Customers where customerId in (1,2,3)
```

Not only is your other suggestion not supported, but also you cannot do any better than this SQL performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a Contains query in Linq to SQL it iwll be fired as an in query in SQL and running your query on the databse should be the fastest..

one caveats to this though is to remember in query might have a limit on the number of entities I think its around 2000+ in sql server and the way around this would be to batch your query.