# How to improve the performance for LINQ query which has "Contains" Operator

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

I am facing slowness while executing the below code. As per my understanding "Contains" Operator is causing the performance issue.

Can anyone help me rewrite the code for better performance.

```
 var listOfBids = (from bid in PropPresUnitOfWork.Bid.GetAll()
                              join bidqueue in PropPresUnitOfWork.BidQueue.GetAll()
                              on bid.BidID equals bidqueue.BidID
                              join bidstatus in PropPresUnitOfWork.BidStatus.GetAll()
                              on bid.BidStatusID equals bidstatus.BidStatusID
                              where bid.LoanNumber == loanNo
                             && (openBids.Contains(bidstatus.BidStatusID))
                              && bidstatus.IsActive == true && (RolesCanDoReview.Contains(bidqueue.BidQueueTypeID))
                              select bidqueue).ToList();
```

Note :  List RolesCanDoReview = new List();
        List openBids = new List() { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {

        return DBSet;

    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085261/linq-query-instead-of-contains-operator-for-performance-issue

Comment: try bringing back just the columns you need in instead of `.GetAll()

Comment: What are your investigation results based on? What is the actual sql query that is generated for this linq statement? Which SQL database are you using?

Answer (score 3):

A `contains` translates to an `in` filter condition in sql. From a performance point of view there is nothing wrong with `in`/ `contains`.

The issue might be caused by a missing index. So what I would do to analyse this problem would be to get the generated sql, execute it in SQL Server Management Studio and have a look at the execution plan.

The easiest way to get the generated sql is to turn on logging like this:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContextClassNameHere())
{
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write;

    // Your code here...
}
```